# html javascript form no longer working since adding new input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html and javascript code for validation on the input fields, this was working with the one input field for first name but since I tried to extend my code by adding a new input field for last name now the form validation has stopped working as follows:

```
function myFunction() {

  let x = document.getElementsByName("first_name").[0]value;
  let y = document.getElementsByName("last_name")[0].value;

  let text;
  text = "";
  
  if (x == '' ||  x == null) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  }
  document.getElementById("first_name_errors").innerHTML = text;
}

  if (y == '' ||  y == null) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  }
  document.getElementById("last_name_errors").innerHTML = text;
}


document.addEventListener('invalid', (function () {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByName("first_name").focus();
    document.getElementsByName("last_name").focus();
  };
})(), true);

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="first_name"  placeholder="first name" name class="input_fields" required>
<div class="error-message" id="first_name_errors"></div>
      <input class="save_btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save_fname" onclick="myFunction()">

<br><br>

<input type="text" name="last_name"  placeholder="last name" name class="input_fields" required>
<div class="error-message" id="last_name_errors"></div>
      <input class="save_btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save_lname" onclick="myFunction()">
```

How can I get this back working with the extra input field last name added? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check your browser's Console? You should have a syntax error. If the best you can say is it's "not working" then that indicates you need to do some debugging...

Comment: Anyway, `}

  if (y == '' ||  y == null) {` ...remove the `}` at the start, as it's (prematurely) closing your function. And `("first_name").[0]value` should be `("first_name")[0].value`. Try and double-check your work a bit more carefully, and also do basic debugging steps such as checking for errors. Your browser is not that far off being a fully-fledged JavaScript IDE under the hood.

Comment: ("first_name").[0]value has the period in the wrong place. That's going to kill things before anything else has a chance to run.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("first_name").focus();
    document.getElementsByName("last_name").focus();` makes no sense. Why do you focus one element and immediately focus a different one? You can logically only focus one element at once. Decide which one should be focused when the page loads, and stick to just that one.

Comment: @ADyson, I've had times where doing a single `focus` didn't work, so for browser cross-compatibility, I had to do it twice. But yeah, that that should probably done on the same field for clearer understanding of what's being done, and include a comment as to what's really going on.

Comment: In which browsers does that cause a problem? Sounds like maybe a legacy issue. But yeah, if that's an issue you'd need to do it on the same field!

Comment: BTW since all your validation is doing is checking for empty fields, that should be covered by the `required` attributes on your form fields anyway (assuming they're within a `<form>...</form>` tag as they should be), so all the JS (except for the focusing bit) is pretty much redundant.

Comment: Why do your inputs randomly have an empty `name` attribute half-way along them, when you've already specified the `name` correctly earlier on? Remove that.

Comment: Why have you got buttons to save the first name and last name separately? That's a very odd UI.

Comment: There's an extra closing brace after document.getElementById("last_name_errors").

Answer (score 0):

there are many errors here. you may find them by your own by debugging your `console.log`

1. error, at `let x = document.getElementsByName("first_name").[0]value;`
2. there are a to many `}`
3. eventlisteners need to be on the input and shouldn't be inside the check function
4. there are empty `name` attributes on your inputs

fixing it blind it would be something like:

```
let firstName = document.getElementsByName('first_name')[0];
let lastName = document.getElementsByName('last_name')[0];

function checkValid() {
  let x = firstName.value;
  let y = lastName.value;

  let text;
  text = '';

  if (x == '' || x == null) {
    text = 'Input not valid';
  }
  document.getElementById('first_name_errors').innerHTML = text;

  if (y == '' || y == null) {
    text = 'Input not valid';
  }
  document.getElementById('last_name_errors').innerHTML = text;
}

firstName.addEventListener('invalid', function () {
  firstName.focus();
});

lastName.addEventListener('invalid', function () {
  lastName.focus();
});
```

```
<input type="text" name="first_name"  placeholder="first name" class="input_fields" required>
<div class="error-message" id="first_name_errors"></div>
  
  <input class="save_btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save_fname" onclick="checkValid()">

<br><br>

  <input type="text" name="last_name"  placeholder="last name" class="input_fields" required>
<div class="error-message" id="last_name_errors"></div>
  
  <input class="save_btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save_lname" onclick="checkValid()">
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - I trie dto use this instead of what i had but not quite working for me unfortunately